# How should marriages be decided and done according to hinduism?

Tags: vedas, rituals, practice, marriage

In hinduism, what things are to be considered for deciding correct match of bride and groom? Also what rituals and practices are needed to be done for the marriage?

Comment: Part dup. of [Which scripture describes the procedure for an ideal marriage including how to find the ideal bride or groom?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11324)

Comment: , "what things are to be considered for deciding correct match of bride and groom" did you mean horoscope matching or procedures?

Comment: If you feel the linked question is not duplicate, clarify " what things are to be considered for deciding correct match of bride and groom?", and flag us to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding marriage ceremony (paNi grahana samskara) we have to refer to the specific grihya sutra of husband/wife or of the acharya who is performing it. The main points are given in short in the grihya sutras and detailed mantra procedure is given in karma kanda texts like Vivaha paddhati etc. Some of the important steps of Vedic marriage are :

Main (mukhya) Sankalpa

Swasti Vachanam

Kalasha Sthapana

Madhuparka vidhanam

Agni sthapanam

Jaya homam

Shakha-uccharanam

laja homam

Saptapadi

graha/surya/dhruva nirikshanam (star gazing)

Vamsha/gotra uccharanam

Aashirvadam

These are some of the steps of vedic marriage along with this kulachara (family customs) and deshachara (regional customs) could be done along with the vedic steps. Based on place, time and conditions some ceremonies can be modified.

Ref:[Paraskara Grihya sutra](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/index.htm)

Comment: Paraskara Grihya sutra.is available [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/index.htm). You may add some verses from it.

Comment: Good one! That's what I was saying, people(especially mods) will help you find Grihya sutras.