# What is the significance of circumambulating the sacred fire by bride and groom in marriage?

Tags: rituals, culture, marriage, tradition

**EXPLANATION :**

- In Hindu marriage **Sacred Fire** is used as a important ritual by all the people.
- During the rituals the **Bride and Groom circumambulate** the Sacred Fire for 7 times(Not Sure).

**QUESTION :**

- What is the **Meaning of circumambulating the Sacred Fire** by the bride and groom ?
- How **Many times** should the couples circle the Sacred Fire ?
- What does the Circumambulating of **Each round** of Sacred fire signify ?

Comment: The couple circles the fire altar many times in different ceremonies. 7 times is not said in scriptures it is only seven steps known as Saptapadi. It is explained in [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/what-are-the-saptapadi-or-the-seven-promises-of-marriage/11805#11805) answer. All the rituals in the marriage are explained in [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11324/which-scripture-describes-the-procedure-for-an-ideal-marriage-including-how-to-f/17397#17397) answer.