# What is the scriptural reference to "we will be together till 7 birth" as a married couple?

Tags: marriage

In marriage we take 7 pheras around fire. We do this because we(husband and wife) will be together for 7 births

What is the scriptural reference to this.

Comment: Marriage there are only 4 pheras for dharma artha kama moksha. 7 pheras is Hindi tv serials. See accepted answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11324/which-scripture-describes-the-procedure-for-an-ideal-marriage-including-how-to-f

Comment: @Archit there are no 7 pheras in real life.

Comment: hahaha no I’ve seen 1-2 marriages there are only 4. I don’t know the significance of 4 but heard it’s related to dharma artha kama moksha. If you speak about 7 then there are 7 vows husband wife give each other. See this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/what-are-the-saptapadi-or-the-seven-promises-of-marriage