# What is the role of elder brother in a woman's marriage ceremony?

Tags: marriage

What is the role of elder brother in a woman's marriage ceremony ?
Is there any role specified for the elder brother in the hindu wedding ceremony ? Or any role in her marriage ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? Check Laja Homa Section. [Which scripture describes the procedure for an ideal marriage including how to find the ideal bride or groom?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11324/which-scripture-describes-the-procedure-for-an-ideal-marriage-including-how-to-f)

Comment: In the absence or excommunication of the father, the elder brother performs vriddhisraddha from the bride's side of the family & performs kanyadana.